# What to do with posters editing errors back into their question

Tags: discussion, editing

[This](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83552/editor-in-chief-sent-an-email-asking-to-resubmit-a-manuscript-what-does-it-mean) question made me think of asking, but it's actually the third time I've come across it in the last few months.  In one earlier case the user actually rolled back edits fixing their grammar.

This isn't regarding changes to the substance; the user wrote a post with grammar errors, another user fixed them, then the original user edited it again to add errors back.

In the previous cases I just left it alone, and I'm inclined to do so again.  But then we have posts with bad grammar lying about that really should be fixed.  It seems equally unproductive to engage in a discussion with the OP in the comments, along the lines of "please stop editing grammar errors into your post".  Is this something a mod can address?  Should the post be re-edited again with the hope the OP realizes their error and doesn't repeat the cycle?

Comment: Here's another instance: http://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/84162/revisions

Answer (score 8):

Note that it may not be intentional - weird things can happen if the OP has a post open for editing, someone else edits the post, and then the OP submits their edit.

Anyways, what to do? [As suggested here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3379/11365):

> If your edit is rolled back (either by the original author of the post or another user), *don't* get in an [edit war](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/).
>
> - If the edit is minor, let it go.
> - If the edit is substantial and you think the user may have reverted your edit accidentally, or without understanding why you have made it, you can leave a comment explaining your position and asking for clarification.
> - If the edit is important, you have left a comment, and the issue still has not been resolved, you can raise a flag asking for a moderator to take a look.

Comment: *Note that it may not be intentional - weird things can happen if the OP has a post open for editing, someone else edits the post, and then the OP submits their edit.* – This seems particularly likely in this case as the second edit in question was submitted less than two minutes after the first one. Also, the edit didn’t touch the title.

Comment: Perhaps SE should start using a diff/merge system for edits..

Comment: Or request that the user revise his edit and if necessary perform a merge himself if a concurrent edit has happened (like some phpbb forums do).